# `Result of operator '<' is unused` when in reality it's used

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I'm wondering if this is a bug in XCode or if I'm doing something wrong:

I have this class which implements `Comparable`:

```swift
class Span: Comparable {
    var start: Int
    var end: Int

    // Some stuff skipped 

    static func < (lhs: Span, rhs: Span) -> Bool {
        lhs.start < rhs.start
    }

    static func == (lhs: Span, rhs: Span) -> Bool {
        lhs.start == rhs.start
    }
}
```

XCode complains about both `func <` and `func ==` declarations as

`Result of operator '<' is unused` and `Result of operator '==' is unused`

They are indeed never explicitly called in my code, but they are used as

```swift
var spans: [Span] = []
spans.append(Span(....))
...
spans.append(Span(....))
spans.sort() // sort() calls operator '<' for a Comparable type Span
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in XCode?

**EDITED**: NO `return` is not missing. It's implicit. Code compiles just fine. It's the warning that I'm asking about. No more answers about "missing return". Thank you.

Comment: Add `return` before `lhs.start < rhs.start` and `lhs.start == rhs.start`

Comment: Please do not add any more comments about missing return. It's not missing. It's implicit and the code compiles just fine. My question is about the warning I'm getting.

Comment: *Implicit return* is related to closures. In a declared function you have to **return** the return value.

Comment: @vadian, I've copy pasted code and it says exactly that: `Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'`. `Gene S` you should try to listen and just add `return`.

Comment: @GeneS, here's the image proof: https://imgur.com/a/XPDjPnL And `Repl.it` link: https://repl.it/repls/PrestigiousImprobablePhase

Comment: Maybe you are from the future, but currently implicit return only exists for [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html). There is a [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md) to allow it for ordinary functions, but it is not implemented yet.

Comment: You have tagged the question with Swift 4.2, and your code does *not* compile in Xcode 10.1. As said above, implicit returns for single-expression *functions* have been proposed (and accepted) for a future Swift version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` a bool value

```
static func < (lhs: Span, rhs: Span) -> Bool {
    return lhs.start < rhs.start
}

static func == (lhs: Span, rhs: Span) -> Bool {
    return lhs.start == rhs.start
}
```